# Chrome dev tools with node when using babel

Tags: node.js, babeljs, node-inspector

I am unable to connect with chrome to debug my node app, that is running in my docker.

This is my command:

`"dev": "nodemon -w src --exec 'babel-node --inspect=1234 src --presets es2015,stage-2'"`

And this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
 express:
    build: .
    ports:
     - 3001:3000
     - 1234:1234
```

This is the log:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1234/61dd50d6-3190-445a-9316-79383758aced
express_1  | For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
express_1  | 17 Jul 02:49:30 - Listening on port 3000
```

I configure `127.0.0.1:1234` in `chrome://inspect/#devices`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried opening the url in a new Chrome tab? If I am not using [Node Inspector Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en) then that is how I do it

Comment: I tried it, it does not work.